# Use JQuery to target div container for hide/show div without using ID's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script below and wanted to target the show/hide div as the check boxes are clicked without using ID's and restricting the hide/show feature within each container. Any suggestions?

Here is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/45NRN/2/

And here is the jquery code.

```
$('.c-input').live('change', 'checkbox', function() {
    var target = $(this).prev('.showHideDiv');
    if ($(this).find('input:checked').length == 0) {
        target.hide();
    } else {
        target.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you this solution worked great also. I appreciate your expertise in helping to identify the issues I was having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
$('.c-input').live('change', ':checkbox', function() {
    var target = $(this).closest('.c-input').prev().find('.showHideDiv');
    if ($(this).find('input:checked').length == 0) {
        target.hide();
    } else {
        target.show();
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/45NRN/3/)

Some comments:

- Replaced `'checkbox'` by `':checkbox'`. Your selector finds tags with name `checkbox` (`<checbox\>`,that's not what you're looking for
- `this` in your context is the checkbox and not the `.c-input` element. I changed the related selector to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do this *Working demo* :- ) http://jsfiddle.net/P8UFL/

- Issue was you are using `.prev` for the element which is inside another `div` --> `wrap`

Hence, to traverse through it correctly you probably need to do the `prev` on `wrap` and then `find` `showHideDiv`

- Also HTML is bit invalid > chuck in `/>` with your checkboxes tag.
- `.live` is depricated from 1.7 > Jquery version; alternative is `.on` just a note.

Hope this helps `:)`

**Code**

```
  var target = $(this).prev('.wrap').find(".showHideDiv");
```